# Maven eclipse run Test Suite

Tags: unit-testing, maven, junit, sonarqube, test-suite

this is the maven surefire plugin i am using

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <configuration>
    <includes>
    <include>runner.TestSuite.java</include>
    </includes>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This is testSuite class

```
package runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

import action.TestLogin;
import action.TestRegister;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ TestRegister.class, TestLogin.class })
public class TestSuite {
}
```

Test Suite runs fine on alone.
But when I run maven-Install with eclipse I want to run the test suite without running all the test cases individually. But it says

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) @ FinalProject ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
```

Also I am using sonar to check line coverage which is also not able to detect testSuite I made.
I am new to Junit TestSuite & do not know how to configure them with maven & sonar.

Any link, reference or clue will be helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: Remove the line `<skipTests>true</skipTests>` otherwise the test won't run.

Comment: thanks for the reply though it is not helpful as I want maven to run the TestSuite class & through which the test cases should run.
But if remove the line as you say all the test cases will be run by maven which is not desirable.
Please tell if you are clear with the question.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have JUnit dependency specified in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is the only step that is required to get started - you can now create tests in your test source directory.

More on this at [Maven Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have the mentioned dependency.
What I want is when I run maven-install the test suite should run.
But this do not happen because of <skipTests>true</skipTests> this line;I need this line so that maven do not run test cases in the order it gets.